# Run shell script in python

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu-11.04, subprocess

I need to execute a shell script to run the python program in via python command.

I should have to execute my python script like this

```
ubuntu@ip-10-32-157-231:~/hg_intcen/lib$ xvfb-run python webpage_scrapper.py  http://www.google.ca/search?q=navaspot
```

This script need to be executed in python program since there are huge links has to be passed to that module.

I have searched to execute this shell script in python,so i used "subprocess"

The main thing is when you run this shell command it takes some time to return the result.
i need the python module to execute this command as well as it has to wait for while to return the result.This is required.

I used subprocess.Popen it doesn't return the result like what i got from the bash

```
import subprocess
def execute_scrapping(url):
   exe_cmd = "xvfb-run python lib/webpage_scrapper.py"+" "+str(url)
   print "cmd:"+exe_cmd
   proc = subprocess.Popen(exe_cmd,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   time.sleep(15)
   sys.stdout.flush()
   d=proc.stdout.readlines()
   return d[1]
```

this above is not run into exact result.
Could you please suggest me to execute the bash shell command via python and get the result?

Comment: Running Python from *within* Python? Ugh. Is there any reason you cannot import that script and use it as a module?

Comment: yes ofcourse. The reason is "xvfb-run".It only executes my python module.xvfb is x virtual frame buffer.along with xvfb only that module will give the result.

Comment: http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/

Comment: You might be able to replace xvfb-run with [PyVirtualDisplay](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay). Then you could import webpage_scrapper.py instead of using subprocess.

Comment: @unutbu It is not working with pyvirtualdisplay also..that xvfb command only doing that  Is that any error?       >>> from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
>>> Display(visible=1, size=(320, 240)).start()
>>> crawl(url)
manage.py: cannot connect to X server :1188

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
proc.wait()
```

instead of your `time.sleep(15)` call.

From the docs:

> Popen.wait() - Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the *[communicate()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)* method to wait that the external process completes.

```
stddata, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

If you have to exchange messages between the two process then look into the [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) module:

From the website:

```
   import pexpect
   child = pexpect.spawn ('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
   child.expect ('Name .*: ')
   child.sendline ('anonymous')
   child.expect ('Password:')
   child.sendline ('noah@example.com')
   child.expect ('ftp> ')
   child.sendline ('cd pub')
   child.expect('ftp> ')
   child.sendline ('get ls-lR.gz')
   child.expect('ftp> ')
   child.sendline ('bye')
```